# Convert the raw data with spaces to the relevant data type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have copied some data from the webpage to a text file. How to convert this data to the relevant data format

So that I can have the **list of student data** as `student=[s1,s2,s3]` and *details can be accessed as* `s1.RollNo`, `s2.Name` as classes using python. This *data has a lot of spaces* in it. I have done file handling operation and have saved each line as a list of strings.

Data is as follows:

```
RollNo   Marks       Name
1         55         Ram
2         100        Shayam 
3         91         Tom
4         72         Sweety
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the library `namedtuple` and will use the regular expression to remove the access spaces. In this code first, a namedtuple class is created named student.

> Named tuples are especially useful for assigning field names to data.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import re
...
#file handling operations
# my_list=['RollNo   Marks       Name','1         55         Ram','2         100        Shayam'...]
...

#this will replace the spaces to the comma and will save all the fieldnames
fields = re.sub(' +',',',my_list[0])

student = namedtuple('student',fields)
student_list=[]

for i in range(1,len(my_list)):
    x=re.sub(' +',' ',my_list[i]).split(' ')
    student_list.append(student(x[0],x[1],x[2]))

print(student_list[0].Name)
print(student_list[1].Marks)

#output:

#Ram
#100
```

Answer (score 1):

**@Rajat**, you can try the below code to read data from text file (Here it's `students.txt`) and store data in class object.

> 1. Design your class, here it is **Student**.
> 2. Design a function which takes file path as parameter and returns a list of **Student** objects after processing text file.

» students.txt

```
RollNo   Marks       Name
1         55         Ram
2         100        Shayam 
3         91         Tom
4         72         Sweety
```

» read_file_and_store.py

```
class Student:
    """
    Constructor which constructs a Student object
    """
    def __init__(self, roll_no, marks, name):
        self.roll_no = roll_no;
        self.marks = marks;
        self.name = name;


def read_data_from_file_store(file_path):
    """
    This function reads data from file and store in the objects of type Student
    """ 
    students = [] # A list of objects of type Student
    with open(file_path) as f:
        lines = f.readlines();
        print (lines, end="\n")

        for line in lines[1:]:
            arr = line.strip().split();
            roll_no = int(arr[0]); 
            marks = int(arr[1]); # Converting string to integer
            name = " ".join(arr[2:]); # It will store multiword names (e.g Rishikesh Agrawani)

            # Creating Student object then storing it in a list
            student = Student(roll_no, marks, name);
            students.append(student);

    return students;


# Starting point
if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_path = "E:\\Users\\Rishikesh\\Python3\\Practice\\ReadAndStore\\students.txt"
    students = read_data_from_file_store(file_path);

    # As we know, in this case we have 4 students so the following statements are correct
    # Otherwise you can use loop through list and print the data stored in objects
    s1 = students[0];
    s2 = students[1];
    s3 = students[2];

    # This is what you want
    print("Student 1:\n");
    print("Roll no: ", s1.roll_no); 
    print("Marks  : ", s1.marks);
    print("Name   : ", s1.name, end='\n');

    print("Student 2:\n");
    print("Roll no: ", s2.roll_no); 
    print("Marks  : ", s2.marks);
    print("Name   : ", s2.name, end='\n');

    print("Student 2:\n");
    print("Roll no: ", s3.roll_no); 
    print("Marks  : ", s3.marks);
    print("Name   : ", s3.name, end='\n');
```

» Output

```
E:\Users\Rishikesh\Python3\Practice\ReadAndStore>python read_file_and_store.py
['RollNo   Marks       Name\n', '1         55         Ram\n', '2         100        Shayam \n', '3         91         Tom\n', '4         72         Sweety']

Student 1:

Roll no:  1
Marks  :  55
Name   :  Ram
Student 2:

Roll no:  2
Marks  :  100
Name   :  Shayam
Student 2:

Roll no:  3
Marks  :  91
Name   :  Tom
```